# subversion post-commit hook: print an error message that the user can see?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a Subversion repository created with Subversion 1.6.x.

This repository has a post-commit hook, which performs an action every time a user checks in the file.

Sometimes this post-commit hook fails, and any error messages are simply sent into the ether. Can I create a post-commit hook which prints an error message for the user, so that the user knows that the post-commit hook failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output to `stderr` from your script should be marhsalled back to the client. If you have control over the output yourself, consider appending `>&2` to the relevant `echo`es

ref: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit

This will get the output as far as the svn client libraries, but I'm not sure that every client implementation will do anything with it.

Comment: Ah! These are messages which are not printed to stderr, nor do they generate a non-zero exit status. Maybe that is why I do not see them.

Comment: Indeed. If the message goes to stdout, then it's lost. If you can't modify the hook directly, then wrap it in a script that captures the relevant parts of the output and echoes it to stderr.